# Sumar el resultado de un método de instancia para todos los registros de una tabla en Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un método llamado "cantidad_entradas_salidas" que me devuelve un flotante para cada registro en mi tabla de productos.

Estoy intentando sumar cada resultado de producto_entradas_salidas para obtener una sola cantidad con inject, pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
[16] pry(main)> Producto.all.each { |f| f.cantidad_entradas_salidas(Date.today).inject(:+) }
NoMethodError: undefined method `inject' for 3.0:Float
from (pry):15:in `block in __pry__'
```

De antemano les agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar

```
Producto.all.map{|p| p.cantidad_entradas_salidas(Date.today)}.reduce(:+)
```

Sobre el error, el inject lo estas aplicando a un tipo de dato Float y no al resultado lo cual es incorrecto ya que la clase Float no tiene un método inject.

Comment: Muchas gracias Joel, tienes toda la razón!